# helm chart deployment liveness and readiness failed error

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I have an Openshift cluster. I have created one custom application and am trying to deploy it using Helm charts. When I deploy it on Openshift using '**oc new-app**', the deployments works perfectly fine. But when I deploy it using helm chart, it does not work.

Following is the output of '**oc get all**' ----

```
[root@worker2 ~]#
[root@worker2 ~]# oc get all
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/chart-acme-85648d4645-7msdl            1/1     Running            0          3d7h
pod/chart1-acme-f8b65b78d-k2fb6            1/1     Running            0          3d7h
pod/netshoot                               1/1     Running            0          3d10h
pod/sample1-buildachart-5b5d9d8649-qqmsf   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   672        2d9h
pod/sample2-686bb7f969-fx5bk               0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   674        2d9h
pod/vjobs-npm-96b65fcb-b2p27               0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   817        47h

NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/chart-acme            LoadBalancer   172.30.174.208   <pending>     80:30222/TCP   3d7h
service/chart1-acme           LoadBalancer   172.30.153.36    <pending>     80:30383/TCP   3d7h
service/sample1-buildachart   NodePort       172.30.29.124    <none>        80:32375/TCP   2d9h
service/sample2               NodePort       172.30.19.24     <none>        80:32647/TCP   2d9h
service/vjobs-npm             NodePort       172.30.205.30    <none>        80:30476/TCP   47h

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/chart-acme            1/1     1            1           3d7h
deployment.apps/chart1-acme           1/1     1            1           3d7h
deployment.apps/sample1-buildachart   0/1     1            0           2d9h
deployment.apps/sample2               0/1     1            0           2d9h
deployment.apps/vjobs-npm             0/1     1            0           47h

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/chart-acme-85648d4645            1         1         1       3d7h
replicaset.apps/chart1-acme-f8b65b78d            1         1         1       3d7h
replicaset.apps/sample1-buildachart-5b5d9d8649   1         1         0       2d9h
replicaset.apps/sample2-686bb7f969               1         1         0       2d9h
replicaset.apps/vjobs-npm-96b65fcb               1         1         0       47h
[root@worker2 ~]#
[root@worker2 ~]#
```

As per above diagram, you can see the deployment '**vjobs-npm**' gives a '**CrashLoopBackOff**' error.

Below is the output of '**oc describe pod**' ----

```
[root@worker2 ~]#
[root@worker2 ~]# oc describe pod vjobs-npm-96b65fcb-b2p27
Name:         vjobs-npm-96b65fcb-b2p27
Namespace:    vjobs-testing
Priority:     0
Node:         worker0/192.168.100.109
Start Time:   Mon, 31 Aug 2020 09:30:28 -0400
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=vjobs-npm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=vjobs-npm
              pod-template-hash=96b65fcb
Annotations:  openshift.io/scc: restricted
Status:       Running
IP:           10.131.0.107
IPs:
  IP:           10.131.0.107
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/vjobs-npm-96b65fcb
Containers:
  vjobs-npm:
    Container ID:   cri-o://c232849eb25bd96ae9343ac3ed1539d492985dd8cdf47a5a4df7d3cf776c4cf3
    Image:          quay.io/aditya7002/vjobs_local_build_new:latest
    Image ID:       quay.io/aditya7002/vjobs_local_build_new@sha256:87f18e3a24fc7043a43a143e96b0b069db418ace027d95a5427cf53de56feb4c
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 31 Aug 2020 09:31:23 -0400
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Mon, 31 Aug 2020 09:30:31 -0400
      Finished:     Mon, 31 Aug 2020 09:31:22 -0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Liveness:       http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from vjobs-npm-token-vw6f7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  vjobs-npm-token-vw6f7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  vjobs-npm-token-vw6f7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  68s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned vjobs-testing/vjobs-npm-96b65fcb-b2p27 to worker0
  Normal   Killing    44s                kubelet, worker0   Container vjobs-npm failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulling    14s (x2 over 66s)  kubelet, worker0   Pulling image "quay.io/aditya7002/vjobs_local_build_new:latest"
  Normal   Pulled     13s (x2 over 65s)  kubelet, worker0   Successfully pulled image "quay.io/aditya7002/vjobs_local_build_new:latest"
  Normal   Created    13s (x2 over 65s)  kubelet, worker0   Created container vjobs-npm
  Normal   Started    13s (x2 over 65s)  kubelet, worker0   Started container vjobs-npm
  Warning  Unhealthy  4s (x4 over 64s)   kubelet, worker0   Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.131.0.107:80/: dial tcp 10.131.0.107:80:
 connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  1s (x7 over 61s)   kubelet, worker0   Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.131.0.107:80/: dial tcp 10.131.0.107:80
: connect: connection refused
[root@worker2 ~]#
```

Comment: Add output of `kubectl describe podname` and `kubectl get events`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm using oc instead of kubectl. I have added oc describe podname as well as oc get events.

Comment: What actions the pod do? Is there any process that you run or a script ?

Comment: When you run Helm you provide it with YAML files and not PNG files.  Can you edit the question to replace these images with the actual code and output you're getting?  "CrashLoopBackOff status with exit 1" often suggests the container is starting up but crashing, and I would look at the container logs.

Comment: As mentioned before, please pot the container's error.

Comment: Hi Arghya, The image that I am trying to run is a podman image. In this, there is a React JS build which I am uncompressing in '/var/www/html' and the content is served through httpd (apache). I have tested the image using podman and deployed this image using 'oc new-app' in Openshift. It works perfectly fine there !!!

Comment: Could you post your helm or pod spec?